# Spring Integration With JMS Not Working Properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Hi I was trying to build a Spring boot application , with spring integration

**Application 1 : Publisher**

```
Jms Message -> Broker ->queue1
```

**Application 2: Subscriber & Publisher**

```
Broker->queue1->Transform->HTTP CALL->HTTP Response->JMS Message->Broker->queue2
```

**Publisher Flow**

```
@Configuration
public class EchoFlowOutBound {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow toOutboundQueueFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel")
                .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                    .requestDestination("amq.outbound1")).get();
           }
}

//Gateway

@MessagingGateway
public interface EchoGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel")
    String echo(String message);
}
```

**Subscriber & Publisher Flow**

```
@Configuration
public class MainOrchestrationFlow {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private QueueChannel jmsOutChannel;


     @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow orchestrationFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(
                    Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                            .destination("amq.outbound1")
                            .outputChannel(jmsOutChannel))
                    .<String, String>transform(s -> {
                        return s.toLowerCase();
                    })
                    // HTTP part goes here
                    .<String, HttpEntity>transform(HttpEntity::new)
                   .handle(            
Http.outboundChannelAdapter("http://localhost:8080/uppercase")
                                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                                    .extractPayload(true)
                                    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                    )
                    // and here HTTP part ends
                    .handle(
                            Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
.destination("amq.outbound2")
                    )
                    .get();
        }

}
```

When i run the application, I'm getting error

> Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException:
>   failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 5000ms  at
>   org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:762)
>   ~[spring-integration-jms-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong,

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for pointing that, don't worry about the url, I just put it as dummy there, The error i'm getting is not an http

Comment: If a HTTP call is done and that HTTP call doesn't complete but takes longer to timeout than your JMS message handler, then you get this problem.

Comment: @Gimby I tried with out http part also, it's the same error i'm getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that your consumer is not a `request-reply`. You receive message from the `amq.outbound1` and send to the `amq.outbound2`. That's all: nothing more happens. You have there a `one-way` flow.

At the same time your producer is a `request-reply` - `handle(Jms.outboundGateway(connectionFactory)`. That Outbound Gateway really expects a reply in the `ReplyTo` header according default options for JMS request-reply scenarios.

So, you have to determine for yourself: or you need send reply back to the producer or you just need send-and-forget from that producer. See `Jms.outboundAdapter()` if that.

In case of request-reply you don't need a `Jms.outboundAdapter()` on the consumer side: you must use a `Jms.inboundGateway()` instead of the `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`.

Comment: thank for the help. It solved the issue . I have read this information before form your own answer and missed it.